# Sort a CSV file by first column 1 strictly using php or javascript

Tags: javascript, php, csv, sorting

This is my table which I am displaying using PHP from a CSV file

[image: 1]

I want to sort it such that all rows of m1 come first, then a blank line, then m2 and so on.

This is my code which i use to display the CSV file as a table.

```
<?php
$filename = basename(__FILE__, ".php");
$f = fopen("$filename.csv", "r");
while (($line = fgetcsv($f)) !== false) {
        echo "<tr>";
        foreach ($line as $cell) {
                echo "<td>" . htmlspecialchars($cell) . "</td>";
        }
        echo "</tr>\n";
}
fclose($f);
echo "\n</tbody></table></body></html>";
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use below code to render your table. This is how it works:

1. It creates a data array first form the CSV file
2. then it sorts the first column ascending order
3. loop through each line and render table

   ```
    $mdarray = array();
    $filename = basename(__FILE__, ".php");
    $f = fopen("$filename.csv", "r");

    while (($line = fgetcsv($f)) !== false) {
    {
       array_push($mdarray, $line);
    }
    fclose($f);

    foreach ($mdarray as $key => $row) {
       $names[$key]  = $row[0];
    }

    array_multisort($names, SORT_ASC, $mdarray);
    //array_multisort(array_column($mdarray, 0), SORT_ASC, $mdarray);//php version >=5.5

    foreach ($mdarray as $line) {
       echo "<tr>";
       foreach ($line as $cell) {
               echo "<td>" . htmlspecialchars($cell) . "</td>";
       }
       echo "</tr>\n";

      echo "<hr>"; // blank line
   }
   ```

Comment: Thank you so much, but there's an error 

Call to undefined function array_column() 

and it doesn't show anything at all.

Comment: Which php version are you using?

Comment: I have updated my code to support older version of php

Comment: @Gaurav please don't forget to mark it as accepted one so that others can get help from it in the future

Comment: is the open bracket just after the while statement necessary?!

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH BRO.! IT WORKED LIKE A CHARM.!